# Bootstrap modal not showing at the desired position on a web page when the screen size is smaller

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

This is working fine on the desktop size screen but when the screen size is smaller than 768px and I click in any Image the Modal shows in the centre of the screen.
You can see this behaviour by opening [[tweakball](www.tweakball.com)](https://tweakball.com) all wallpapers navgation on mobile screen

I want the modal to be shown exactly at that point of website where the image is clicked

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <style>
  body {
      background-color: #373737 !important;
    }
    
    .modal-container {
      position: relative !important;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #373737;
      z-index: 10;
      display: none;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .modal-dialog {
      margin: 20px auto 0;
      width: 100% !important;
      height: 100% !important;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .modal-content {
      align-self: center;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: none;
      margin: 0;
      position: absolute !important;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    .modal-body-container {
      width: 80%;
      max-height: 80vh;
      background-color: black;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      /* Center horizontally */
      border-radius: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .modal-body img {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      height: auto;
      width: auto;
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: block;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    .btn-primary {
      background-color: #ffc107;
      border-color: #ffc107;
      color: #000;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      border-bottom: none;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .btn-primary:hover,
    .btn-primary:focus {
      background-color: #ffcd38;
      border-color: #ffcd38;
      color: #000;
    }
    
    body.modal-open {
      overflow: visible;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .btn-secondary {
      background-color: #007bff;
      border-color: #007bff;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    .btn-secondary:hover,
    .btn-secondary:focus {
      background-color: #0056b3;
      border-color: #0056b3;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .modal-footer {
      align-self: center;
      text-align: left;
      border-top: none;
    }
    
    .modal-footer .btn {
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Your existing gallery code here -->

  <!-- Container for modal background -->
  <div class="modal-container">

    <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="imageModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class=" d-flex flex-column modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body-container">
            <img id="modalImage" src="" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <a id="downloadLink" href="javascript" download="image" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Your existing script code here -->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.elementor-gallery-item').each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var imageUrl = $(this).attr('href');
          $('#modalImage').attr('src', imageUrl);
          $('#downloadLink').attr('href', imageUrl);
          var imagePosition = $(this).offset();
          var imageTop = imagePosition.top;
          var imageLeft = imagePosition.left;
          $('#modalImage').css({
            'top': imageTop + 'px',
            'left': imageLeft + 'px'

          });
          $('#imageModal').modal('show');
          $('.modal-container').show(); // Show the modal background container
          // window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        });
      });

      // Close the modal and hide the background container
      $('#imageModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $('.modal-container').hide();
      });
    });
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      // Your existing script code

      // Adjust z-index dynamically when modal is shown
      $('#imageModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        // Ensure backdrop and modal are siblings
        $(this).before($('.modal-backdrop'));
        // Set z-index of modal greater than backdrop
        $(this).css("z-index", parseInt($('.modal-backdrop').css('z-index')) + 1);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```